# Splitting a pdf at irregular intervals

Tags: python, pdf, split

I'm using the below code to split a pdf of varied invoices:

However, I am trying to get this for loop to iterate over irregular intervals (e.g. the first split should be just page 1, the second split should be pages 2-4, third split - 5-6, etc.)

Could someone perhaps help me modify this code to achieve the desired result?

Thanks very much!

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open("document.pdf", "rb"))

for i in range(inputpdf.numPages):
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
    with open("document-page%s.pdf" % i, "wb") as outputStream:
        output.write(outputStream)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this, `end_of_split` is assumed to be `true` for the last page of each split, include the last split:

```
def end_of_split(n):
    return n%2==0
output = PdfFileWriter()
out_count = 0
for i in range(inputpdf.numPages):
    output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
    if end_of_split(i):
        with open("document-page%s.pdf" % out_count, "wb") as outputStream:
            output.write(outputStream)
            out_count += 1
        if i < inputpdf.numPages-1:
            output = PdfFileWriter()
```

Comment: Thank you Scott, this is really helpful.